# Delete Google History including searches and browsing activity

Tags: history

Your searches and browsing activity are saved in your **Web & App Activity** when it's turned on and you're signed in to your Google Account. You're in control of what's saved, and you can delete it or turn the setting off whenever you like.

You my wonder how can you delete the history?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Sign into your Google account.

Step 2: Visit https://history.google.com/history/

Step 3: In the top right corner of the page, click the three dots icon and select **Delete Options**

Step 4: Choose time period. To delete your entire history, choose **Advanced** then **All Time**

Step 5: Click **Delete**

[image]